# Export Sql query resultset to a comma separated file using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, export-to-csv

I am polling a file from a unix directory , and creating a external directory using 
following command, and loading the data in the file as table. Later i am applying where condition on the table and the resultset should be exported as a comma separated csv file using JDBC .kindly let me know is it possible, or please point me to some blog .

```
Create or replace directory
```

and

```
Alter table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very [good starting place](http://www.isocra.com/2004/10/dumptosql/). I personnally use some code inspired by their example and it works great to dump a resultset into a SQL file that you can load into a table very easily. You could adapt it to your needs in a few minutes.